# How to compile linphone using local linhpone SDK for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linphone, linphone-sdk

So far i have build my own linphone SDK. Now i need to compile and builld my project using my SDK. but when download the linphone code using this, 
git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone.git and i have run the this command inside the downloaded folder,

1. PODFILE_PATH='path to linphone-sdk-ios' pod install

error said i don't have " No podspec found doe 'linphone sdk' ", I think here I don't know how to give the path for sdk or i might be run this command in the wrong place. Please i need to know,

1. How to give the SDK path
2. How to compile the code using local SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this 
`pod 'linphone-sdk', path: 'PATH_TO_LINPHONE/linphone-sdk.podspec'`